# Microsoft Calendar Graph API : Id of event not shared between users

Tags: web-services, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I'm currently working on the Microsoft Calendar Graph API and I ran into some problems when trying to synchronize events.

Basically what I have is 2 users on my web service : they both have an Outlook adress. User A create an event on my web service, and add User B as an attendee. The event is then send to Outlook using the REST API. It's created on User A Outlook calendar, and User B receive an invitation on Outlook and the event is created as well in his Outlook calendar.

Now, on my web service, when the event is created, I retrieve the Microsoft ID of the event and store it in my database. This way, when I want to synchronize events between Outlook calendar and my calendar, all I do is retrieve all Outlook events, check their ID and see if they are stored in my database : if they are, then the event already exists on my web service, if they are not then I create the event in my web service.

The problem I have is that when I try to get the Outlook events from User B, the ID of the event is different than the one I stored earlier, and therefore it creates a duplicate that I don't need.

Basically, the event on User A outlook calendar and User B outlook calendar have different ID. I don't understand what's the point of this, because they are the same, the one on User B outlook calendar is just an invitation to the one from User A outlook calendar.

My question is : is there any way I can get around that ? Is there any kind of ID that is shared through users in Outlook/Office365 ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is precisely what the `iCalUId` property is for. The `id` is by design different, as it's a sort of "primary key" for the user's mailbox database. The `iCalUId` is supposed to be the same across calendars.

From https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event:

> `iCalUId` - String - A unique identifier that is shared by all instances of an event across different calendars.

Answer (score -2):

There is AFAIK no property that is unique and also constant across different mailboxes. You can [add custom properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_post_singlevalueextendedproperties) to events, and make sure that the property value is unique and constant. That would require you to be able to write to User A's events.